# Cross platform UI spacing/padding

Tags: java, linux, macos, swt, miglayout

I have written a Java UI using the SWT UI library and the MigLayout layout library.

This page shows screenshots of the UI on Windows, Linux and OSX: http://mchr3k.github.com/org.intrace/screenshots.html

On Linux and OSX my UI has a lot more padding and spacing which I feel wastes a lot of screen space. Is this normal for these platforms? If not, what is the best way to work around this?

EDIT: the linked screenshots have now been updated and no longer show an extra gap on OSX as I have explicitly set the margins on some of my UI elements to 0. The OSX UI is still quite spaced out but I assume that this is correct for the platform.

Comment: It's as normal as you'll get with crossplatform UI. The point of CP UI is not to look good, but to function—if you want aesthetics, drop the Java and get out the QT and Objective C and .Net.

Comment: @Luxun: It's perfectly possible (and quite easy) to create an acceptable and professional UI in Java which looks good on all the major platforms, simply by requesting the O/S look and feel.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey - Its not quite that simple. I am using SWT to give me native widgets on each platform but it is still important to do testing for platform specific quirks. For example on OSX my jar must be launched with -XstartOnFirstThread and to get my application name shown in the dock I would need to package the jar with an info.plist file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is Mikael Grev, the creator of MigLayout.

As someone else mentioned this is a feature of MigLayout. Instead of using x number of pixels (you can of course use that too) by default it is using gaps like related, unrelated and paragraph. These correspond to different sizes in different UI toolkits. For instance on OS X the recommended white space between components is larger than on Windows.

So, yes, this is how it's supposed to look and it will look correct for a native OS X user.

You do seem to have too much white space at the bottom of the Output pane though, in both OS X and Windows.

You can use the PlatformDefaults class in MigLayout to either force a platform or to change the default gaps. Check the source code if you want to know what's happening behind the scenes.

And remember, this is a feature so that every developer won't have to keep track of how to spacing should look like on different platforms, which is kind of hard.

Cheers,
Mikael

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you decide to register an account using your name, this [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste) on merging may be of interest.

Comment: Do you really mean on Windows and OSX? I think on Windows I have very little whitespace. I've taken another look and OSX is the only platform which I now feel has too much space at the bottom. Is there any easy way to work out if I have "excess" space? I tried turning on Miglayout "debug" mode but this didn't seem to display anything extra on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a feature of MigLayout, if I recall correctly.  If you don't want this I am sure you could so configure MigLayout.  Otherwise, you could use a different layout manager (but I still highly recommend a table-based one) which uses constant spacing for all platforms (such as my [MatrixLayout](http://www.softwaremonkey.org/Code/MatrixLayout)).

Comment: Which feature of Miglayout do you think is adding this spacing on Linux/OSX?