# Why is Linux Java UI larger than Windows Java UI?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, user-interface, fedora

I'm using both Fedora 17 and Windows 7 for my software development, and I'm using Eclipse.

One thing that I noticed with the Eclipse in Fedora 17 and in Windows 7 is the workspace.
Apparently the element spacing in Fedora is much larger than in Windows 7, resulting in smaller typing area for Eclipse in Fedora than in Windows 7.

I also noticed that the large element spacing happens not only in Eclipse, but also on any Java GUI program that I run on Fedora 17.

Does anybody know how to deal with this kind of issue?

Comment: I don't know about any GUI framework that can guarantee you that your widgets will have the same aspect on all platforms. It's a normal behaviour, try to design your widgets in pixel or points and express a precise dimension for all your widgets.

Comment: Check out Mikael Grev's answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325430/cross-platform-ui-spacing-padding

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12600344/230513) and this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13054540/230513).

Comment: Swing will guarantee the same aspect on all platforms, but that is because it does it's own drawing.  Basically it asks for a certain sized window from the OS, and that's it, the rest it does internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically because they are different OSes, and they have different UI design directives. Moreover, while you have a common interface for java UI libraries like SWT, their implementations are different on each platform and use native libraries.

Comment: Yes, basically, it's not a Java GUI.  It's a platform GUI with a Java API over it.  That's why it's different between platforms, and if you want a Java GUI, use Swing, which _can_ be the same for all platforms.